# How can I run a command if my screen changes state from standby to on and vice versa

Tags: xorg, power-management, display, monitors

I'm running linux mint 17.3.
I have a backlight attached to my screens which are controlable via usb-serial. I would like to turn off the backlight automatically when the screens go to standby and have the light turn on again when the screens turn on.
I can run `xset -q` and get the state but polling seems wrong. Is there a way tu run a script in these situations?

Comment: Isn't there some dbus event you could listen to ? Whichever DE you're using probably emits some event when the screens goes to standby. You could look for what kind of event is emitted looking at `dbus-monitor` output and  use that to run your command using a script like [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/150850).